# jsf - a4j action firing, but after page rendering logic fires

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces, myfaces, ajax4jsf

Using richfaces 3.1.5 with myfaces/jsf and notice when I invoke an a4j action, before it executes, the entire facelet it is on is getting rerendered - I'm remote debugging and when I click the a4j link, I first see my phaseListener get invoked (which makes sense), but then I also see all the logic in my bean getters that are in the facelet containing the a4j action link firing off, then finally the action executing and then its rerenders.  The logic in some of the getters is expensive and so I do not want them to be getting invoked unnecessarily - I just want action click -> invoke action -> rerender zones, rather than this cycle of action click -> rerender entire page -> invoke action -> rerender zones that is happening now.

Don't know if it matters but my a4j action is not mapped to an actionListener but just an action which calls a String method returning null.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee getters will only be called once in JSF. You should move the expensive calls out of getters or do a check before invoking the logic in getters. In general, it's not recommended to put expensive logic in getters (in the context of JSF).

Comment: Hi Max, so the app is url-driven in that the request params sent via it drive the preprocessing - the expensive operation only occurs on the first getter (subsequent getters on the same page referencing the same info check a processed flag to avoid reinvoking the same logic). The beans are request-scoped because it is quite likely multiple tabs/windows will be open using this app.  So then how can I flag processing from the ajax call - I can't do it via the action or an actionParam var since the page render (and getters on it) still uselessly fire before the actual a4j call fires.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand the question. But, Ajax or non-Ajax request, you always go thru the same JSF phases. Skipping to the last two, it's always Invoke Application and then Rendering Response. All actions are always invoked before the page is rendered. Hope this helps.